# phpbb 3.1.6 generates corrupt avatars if some directory permissions are not correct

Tags: php, nginx, phpbb3

### NOTE: Resolved - see answer below. Question kept for reference.

Something is causing nginx or php or phpbb (or something else) to add 1 byte to the beginning of avatar files downloaded from phpbb. This corrupts the file.

To exclude external factors like Cloudflare, I have now setup phpbb as non-https, localhost only, compression off.

The problem can be seen from the following code:

Get the file from localhost - no caching or cloudflare to interfere:

```
wget http://localhost/forum/download/file.php?avatar=4625_1413540046.jpg -O avatest_local.jpg
‘avatest_local.jpg’ saved [6419/6419]
```

Test the file

```
jpeginfo avatest_local.jpg
avatest_local.jpg  Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x0a 0xff  [ERROR]
```

Find the identical file (phpbb does weird things to filenames)

```
find /var/www/forum/images/avatars/upload  -size 6419c
/var/www/forum/images/avatars/upload2a36dc33069249d6b1187fd84d7fc957_4625.jpg
```

Test THAT file and find it to be good

```
jpeginfo /var/www/forum/images/avatars/upload/2a36dc33069249d6b1187fd84d7fc957_4625.jpg
./2a36dc33069249d6b1187fd84d7fc957_4625.jpg   80 x 80   24bit JFIF  N    6419
```

Examine the first few bytes of the original file:

```
xdd /var/www/forum/images/avatars/upload/2a36dc33069249d6b1187fd84d7fc957_4625.jpg
0000000: ffd8 ffe0 0010 4a46 4946 0001 0101 013a  ......JFIF.....:
0000010: 013a 0000 ffed 0036 5068 6f74 6f73 686f  .:.....6Photosho
0000020: 7020 332e 3000 3842 494d 0404 0000 0000  p 3.0.8BIM......
```

Examine the first few bytes of the downloaded file and see the extra bit:

```
xdd avatest_local.jpg
0000000: 0aff d8ff e000 104a 4649 4600 0101 0101  .......JFIF.....
0000010: 3a01 3a00 00ff ed00 3650 686f 746f 7368  :.:.....6Photosh
0000020: 6f70 2033 2e30 0038 4249 4d04 0400 0000  op 3.0.8BIM...
```

Strip the first bit back out of downloaded file to prove the point:

```
tail -c +2 avatest_local.jpg > avatest_fixed.jpg
jpeginfo avatest_fixed.jpg
avatest_fixed.jpg   80 x 80   24bit JFIF  N    6418
```

May or may not be relevant, but if I use the chrome header viewer inspector, the http response headers for avatars show the following:

```
content-disposition inline; filename=4625.jpg
```

But if I use redbot, it shows:

```
Content-Disposition: inline; filename*=UTF-8''4625.jpg
```

and warns that

> The Content-Disposition header doesn't have a 'filename' parameter.

However, on the official phpbb board, the content-disposition headers seem correct, although as you can see below, this doesn't seem to affect other methods of viewing the image.

---

### Summary:

- When downloading or viewing an avatar in the format `/download/file.php?avatar=4625_1413540046.jpg` a single byte is added to the file, making it invalid.
- When viewing an image like `/download/file.php?id=2871` the image is totally valid and displays OK.
- All image files currently on the server are valid.
- I have run php in "lint" mode and all files seem valid.
- I have tried running the board as "localhost" in non-https to completely remove external factors.
- I have disabled all the extensions, and even removed their files.
- This board was upgraded by deleting all core files and copying the new ones over.
- Nginx serves image and other files directly perfectly well, and other software on the same server runs fine.

Server details:

```
nginx 1.9.4
PHP 5.6.4-4ubuntu6.3
phpbb 3.1.6
Linux 3.19.0-30-generic #34-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 2 22:07:32 UTC 2015 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

One entire day spent on this, and both myself and the phpbb forum are totally flummoxed. Only started happening since update to phpbb 3.1.6. Clearly it's a problem unique to me. Or maybe not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### SOLVED IT!

Check permissions

https://www.phpbb.com/support/docs/en/3.0/kb/article/phpbb3-chmod-permissions/

```
chown -R forum:forum forum/

find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

cd forum
chmod 777 cache store files images/avatars/upload/
```

The first bit about chown -R forum:forum forum/ is something I always do after updating anyway, but the chmod is something I THOUGHT I did ages ago. I didn't touch any of those directories when I updated the board.

I wonder if 3.1.6 handles temp and cache files differently from previous versions? All I can think is that phpbb (or something) is trying to cache the response from getting the avatar (?!) and when it found it couldn't, it still send the file but with... with an extra byte?!

But that doesn't even make sense. At all. I can't figure this out at all, but all I can say is that re-doing all the permissions has fixed it.

If anyone can explain what might have happened, I'm all ears!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have some empty line after ?> in php file? This could be reason

Comment: Thank you - that's a good idea but I tried that already - the only place found was in config.php and the situation is the same even after removing that closing tag (the command used was pcregrep -rMl '\?>[\s\n]+\z' * )

Comment: This fixed the issue for me. My config.php had an extra LF at the end of the file. I removed this, and the download works correctly now.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, it turned out to be a blank line accidentally inserted at the beginning of config.php